# how i can draw dotted line in fpdf by using php

Tags: php, line, fpdf

```
        $pdf->SetXY($xx + 2 , $y + 15);
        $pdf->Cell(190, 5, 'Sem Avg', 0, 'C');
        $pdf->SetXY($xx +  22 , $y + 15);
        $pdf->Cell(190, 5, 'Final Avg', 0, 'C');
```

how to draw the verical line to seperate the text between 'Sem Avg' and 'Final Avg'

Comment: There's an addon for that: http://fpdf.de/downloads/addons/33/

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the FPDF class in

> PDF_Dash

By adding the following method to the new class:

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

class PDF_Dash extends FPDF
{
    function SetDash($black=null, $white=null)
    {
        if($black!==null)
            $s=sprintf('[%.3F %.3F] 0 d',$black*$this->k,$white*$this->k);
        else
            $s='[] 0 d';
        $this->_out($s);
    }
}
?>
```

**Example:** for a horizontal

```
<?php
   require('dash.php');

   $pdf=new PDF_Dash();
   $pdf->AddPage();
   $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.1);
   $pdf->SetDash(5,5); //5mm on, 5mm off
   $pdf->Line(20,20,190,20);
   $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.5);
   $pdf->Line(20,25,190,25);
   $pdf->SetLineWidth(0.8);
   $pdf->SetDash(4,2); //4mm on, 2mm off
   $pdf->Rect(20,30,170,20);
   $pdf->SetDash(); //restores no dash
   $pdf->Line(20,55,190,55);
   $pdf->Output();
?>
```

View the result [here.](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/ex33.pdf)

And **for a vertical** line you have to the same value for x1 & x2 and change y1 & y2:

```
$pdf->Line(50,105,50,175);
```

Source of the solution: [here.](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script33.php)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

$pdf->Line($xOfTheStart, $yOfTheStart, $xOfTheEnd, $yOfTheEnd)

Comment: Are you sure about that? How does this produce a dotted line?